# Data.frame becomes factor/vector after filtering/subsetting

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with one column, like so:

```
>d = data.frame(animal=c("horse","dog","cat"))
```

then I filter it by excluding all items also present in a vector. e.g.:

```
> res = d[!(d$animal %in% c("horse")),]
> res
[1] dog cat
Levels: cat dog horse
>class(res)
[1] "factor"
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Also note that the class of the column in your data.frame is not "character", but "factor": `class(d[[1]])`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to R. You've just been bitten by the `drop` annoyance: you need to explicitly tell R not to "drop to one-dimension":

```
res = d[!(d$animal %in% c("horse")), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: See Patrick Burns' R Inferno for a more detailed discussion on this: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S/Spoetry/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: It's funny, I've been using R for 3 or 4 years and this is the first time I've run into this. I guess I typically don't use 1 column data.frames.

Comment: I'm not surprised. It's a subtle thing that comes up while debugging deep inside some function. To quote Patrick Burns from the R Inferno: "Failing to use drop=FALSE inside functions is a major source of bugs. You only test the function when the subscript has length greater than 1. The function fails once it hits a situation where the subscript is length 1|somewhere downstream a matrix is expected and there is a simple vector there instead."